# C: Program won't ask the user again if the user inputs a character using fflush(stdin)

Tags: c, scanf, fflush

Obviously I'm not going to post my whole code here as it IS very long, it is a tax calculator after all. This problem applies to all my scanfs that need double values as input from the user. Basically as the title says, my program doesn't ask the user to input another value even if it's a character, which obviously isn't a double value so some help will be very appreciated. Forgive me as I'm still in the first year of my course and don't know everything about programming.

```
double salary;
printf("This program will compute your yearly and monthly witholding tax for you \n");
printf("How much is your total monthly salary? ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%lf", &salary);
while (salary < 0)
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("Invalid Input\n");
    printf("How much is your total monthly salary? ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%lf", &salary);
}
```

Comment: You need to run tests on the string you receive / convert it into double.

Comment: How do I do that? I've been researching for quite a while and all I found are things that I can't understand at all because we haven't taken that up in class yet.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is not guaranteed to work, according to the C standard, so on some systems it might not work at all.

Comment: Looking at your code, you seem to expect that `salary` will be set to a negative value. That is not something that `scanf`will do. Instead, `scanf` will return the number of things it managed to match, as the return value from the function, so do something like `if (scanf("%lf", &salary) != 1) ....`.

Comment: @Thomas Any suggestions on how to make the program ask the user again if he inputs a character? It seems to work for only one part of my code, and ONLY this part     scanf("%d", &dependents);
      while (dependents < 0 || dependents > 4). P.S how the heck do I properly comment some codes, and nope, salary is supposed to be a positive value. Which is why if salary is lesser than 0, meaning a negative value, it'll ask again.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant But without it an infinite loop happens, with it the program doesn't ask the user again if you input a character, but instead goes on to the next question, even though it's supposed to ask again. As I said in my earlier comment, it only asks again and again if you input a character for one part of my code.

Comment: Consider using a terminal library like [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/) or [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) (at least on Linux systems...)

Comment: @JonnRalgeYuvallos If you want line-by-line input, use `fgets()`, not `scanf()`. (Avoiding the use of `scanf()` is probably a better idea anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

You correctly diagnosed the problem: invalid input stays in the input buffer, causing every subsequent `scanf` to fail. You cannot correct this with `fflush`, because it is not defined for input streams.  Note that you also misuse `scanf` as you do not test the return value.

The simple and generic solution to your problem is this: replace calls to `scanf` with calls to a function that reads a line from the user and parses it as a string repeatedly until either EOF or correct input is entered.

This function takes a range for validity checking.  You can pass infinities if you dont want to accept all input.

```
int getvalue(const char *prompt, double *vp, double low, double high) {
    char buffer[128];
    for (;;) {
        printf("%s ", prompt);
        if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
            printf("EOF reached, aborting\n");
            // you can also return -1 and have the caller take appropriate action
            exit(1);
        }
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf", vp) == 1 && *vp >= low && *vp <= high)
            return 0;
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }
}
```

In your code fragment, you would replace everything with this:

```
double salary;
printf("This program will compute your yearly and monthly withholding tax for you\n");
getvalue("How much is your total monthly salary?", &salary, 0.0, HUGE_VAL);
```

`HUGE_VAL` is defined in `<math.h>`, but its value seem a bit high for a salary anyway, you can just write a decent maximum such as `1E9`.

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so much. I still don't really understand how this fixes it, I've been researching for nearly an hour now yet still haven't found a good fix for it. My teacher recommended using fflush but yeah, as you said it doesn't really work, and as others have said, it shouldn't be used for input anyway. Thanks again. I really really appreciate the help.

Comment: Dont give up so easily!  look up `fgets` online, it is a very useful function for input in most of your C assignments.  `sscanf` works the same as `scanf` but parses a string instead of the stream directly.  This fixes the problem because the user input is read one full line at a time, then analysed, and discarded if incorrect.

Comment: It is tricky to tell your teacher about his mistakes... you can *flush* the input with a simple loop:  `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') continue;`  but it is not needed if you use `fgets()` with a large enough buffer.

Comment: Thank you so much again, I will, and ooooooh I see, our professor has only taught us how to use scanf so far, man programming is complex.  But then again that's why it's so fun to learn. Seriously though. Thanks. A lot.